# How to load php_redis.dll when running post deployment script in Kudu Console

Tags: php, azure, phpredis, kudu

I have a webapp running on Azure App Service. I am trying to test a Post deployment script in Kudu Debug CMD console.

```
php -d extension=php_redis.dll -f postdeploy.php
```

Here is my postdeploy.php file

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function exception_handler($exception) {
    echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

$redis = new Redis();

...

?>
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found in D:\home\site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions\postdeploy.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_redis.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0
```

I uploaded the proper version of php_redis.dll to the PostDeploymentActions folder. This is the same binary that the webapp is using via the app setting in portal `PHP_EXTENSIONS = bin\php_redis.dll`. However, I am not sure how to load this for this script.

Is there a way that I can load the php_redis.dll in Kudu post deployment script?

I tried `php -d extension=./php_redis.dll -f postdeploy.php`, `php -d extension=%~dp0php_redis.dll -f postdeploy.php` and other weird combinations with no luck.

Comment: As a first step, I'd suggest isolating to a simpler Kudu console scenario, per [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add the PHP extension via **ini settings**, refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime at the `Configure via ini settings` section.

Generally:

1. Add an App Setting to your Web App with the key `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` and value `d:\home\site\ini`
2. Create an configuration file in `d:\home\site\ini` called `extensions.ini`
3. Add configuration settings to the `extensions.ini` file using the same
   syntax you would use in a php.ini file. For example:  extension =
   php_redis.dll.
4. Restart Web Apps service.

Via this approach, you can configure the PHP extension into Kudu console site's PHP runtime. And configure via the `App Settings` will only configure the extension into IIS.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: As per the referred link, did a slight change to step 3 - I uploaded the php_redis.dll to `d:\home\site\ext` folder and added  `extension=d:\home\site\ext\php_redis.dll` in extensions.ini file.  Modified post deployment command to `php postdeploy.php`. Everything is working perfectly. Thankyou.